# Adding new column to the existing list

Tags: c#, list, xml-parsing

I have a class  with fields - Id , name, company and  another 29 fields.

```
public class Employee
{
  [XmlAttribute("textbox1")]
  public int Id { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute("textbox11")]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute("textbox21")]
  public string Company { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute("textbox22")]
  public bool Val1 { get; set; }
  [XmlAttribute("textbox23")]
  public bool Val2 { get; set; }
  public bool TestSomething{get;set;}
}


public class ParseData()
{
   List<Employee> employee = new List<Employee>();
   XmlSerialiser serializer = new XmlSerializer();
   using(FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open))
   {
       employees = (Employee)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
   }

  //Todo: Add the new calculated value TestSomething

}
```

I'm deserialising the values from the xml data ( which has around 100 employees).

Now I have a new field 'TestSomething' which is not deserialised but will be result of deserialised value as shown below. Is there a way I could add calculated values to the existing list employees ?

```
foreach(var i in employees)
{
  employee.TestSomething = (Val1 == true) ? Val1 : Val2;
}
```

Any suggestion on this will be appreciated.

Comment: This question is very unclear.  First, `Now I have a new field which has to be calculated based on the values which I get after serialising` what does that mean?  Second, Did you add that **Property** to the class from which the xml is derived?

Comment: @FelixCastor Added more information

Answer (score 0):

The code snippets below are extension methods I use to serialize and deserialize xml strings.  Note these need to be put in a static class and referenced in the class for use.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes the object to xml string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>xml serialization.</returns>
    public static string SerializeToXml<T>(this T instance)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        string result;

        var format = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var strmr = new StringWriter())
        {
            format.Serialize(strmr, instance);
            result = strmr.ToString();
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes xml serialized objects.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xmlDocument">serialized string.</param>
    /// <param name="result">out parameter.</param>
    /// <returns>Instance object.</returns>
    public static bool TryParseXml<T>(this string xmlDocument, out T result)
        where T : class, new()
    {
        result = null;

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(xmlDocument))
        {
            return false;
        }

        try
        {
            using (TextReader str = new StringReader(xmlDocument))
            {
                var format = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(str);
                if (format.CanDeserialize(xmlReader))
                {
                    result = format.Deserialize(xmlReader) as T;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return !(result is null);
    }
```

In practice you would have a class of some type that has properties that you would like to store to a disk or database etc.  Lets say I have a class:

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public double X { get; set;}
    public double Y { get; set;}
}
```

If I wanted to store a list of `MyPoint` without much heavy lifting I could serialize the class directly using the `SerializeToXml` method above.

```
var myPoints = new List<MyPoint>{new MyPoint{ X= 1, Y = 2}, new MyPoint{X = 3, Y = 4}};

var xmlString = myPoints.SerializeToXml();
```

Everything is fine and dandy, my info is saved as xml in some file somewhere.  But then my boss says, "Dang, sorry about this but we need a Z value now that is computed from the X and Y of each using `Z = X * X + Y * Y`."

Adding properties to the serialized class isn't a problem **(taking properties out is!! 
 The serializer will try to assign a value to a property that doesn't exist and throw an exception.)**.  But in this case we don't need to worry.  I go to the original `MyPoint` class and add a Z.

```
public class MyPoint
{
    public double X { get; set;}
    public double Y { get; set;}
    public double Z { get; set;}  // <---- Here
}
```

Now when I parse the xml I will get classes with the new property.  Using the `TryParseXml` I get my list of points.

```
// assume I have a string already from the xml document to use.

List<MyPoint> points = null;

if(serializedPoints.TryParse(out points))
{
    foreach(var point in points)
    {
        point.Z = X * X + Y * Y;
    }
}


var serializedPointsWithZ = points.SerializeToXml();
```

Now `serializedPointsWithZ` is just a string that can be written to a file etc.